# Understanding the sem_open()

Tags: c++, c, synchronization, semaphore

I am using named semaphores, here is my process code of sem_proc.cpp:

```
# include <iostream>
# include <string.h>
# include <unistd.h>
# include <semaphore.h>
# include <fcntl.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  sem_t *sem;
  string sem_name = "/my_sem";
  int value = 1;

  sem = sem_open(sem_name.c_str(), O_CREAT, 0644, value);
  cout << "sem_addr : " << sem << endl;
  
  cout << "sem_wait_result: " << sem_wait(sem) << endl;
  cout << "Enterd into CS" << endl;
  sleep(5);   // sleep for 5 seconds
  cout << "Waked up and now going out of CS" << endl;
  sem_post(sem);
  
  sem_close(sem);
  return 0;
}
```

I have compiled with:

```
g++ sem_proc.cpp -lpthread
```

then run the code on two different terminals as:

```
./a.out
```

Output of terminal 1 was:

```
sem_addr : 0x7fef162de000
sem_wait_result: 0
Enterd into CS
Waked up and now going out of CS
```

Output of terminal 2 was:

```
sem_addr : 0x7f53836a2000
sem_wait_result: 0
Enterd into CS
Waked up and now going out of CS
```

Shouldn't the **address of the named semaphore** with name "/my_sem" in both the terminal be same as I am passing **O_CREAT** to `sem_open()`, or am I missing something?

Comment: There's no reason to me that they should exist at the same address. They're different processes, which might be affected by ASLR, giving different virtual memory layouts. Do note that the both exist on 4 kiB page boundaries.

Comment: In this case, the semaphore file will be `mmap`ed by the `sem_open` implementation, which will leave the choice of virtual address up to the kernel. If the processes are loaded at random virtual addresses, that is going to affect the virtual address chosen by the kernel when the semaphore file is `mmap`ed.

Comment: The addresses you see inside a userspace process are virtual addresses, and don't mean anything, or correspond directly to anything, outside that process. You can even mmap the same physical page into two processes at different virtual addresses (in fact, you can map a physical page into _one_ process at two different virtual addresses)

Comment: ... but technically, this is not specific to C++, and is a detail of UNIX/Linux userspace processes. The same would be true in any other language, whether it exposes addresses to you or not.

Answer (score 0):

Do not expect semaphores to have the same memory address in different processes. This is not the semaphore itself, `sem_t` is the program's copy of data needed to interface with the semaphore. The semaphore itself is handled by the OS.

The exact location is complicated by a lot of factors: Address randomization, malloc, mmap, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A `sem_t`, in POSIX, is a structure that holds information about the semaphore, and it is created usually by calling `mmap` with the flag `MAP_SHARED` to tell the kernel to use a pre-allocated Shared Memory area. Semaphores (in Unix systems) are really just file descriptors, so mapping them into memory needs to be shared amongst threads.

The memory address of this mapping is up to the kernel to decide, based on other mapped files and areas, and that explains why it is different each time. The kernel will randomize the address layout, in order to prevent exploits caused by buffer-overflows.

For more information, read up on the [mmap](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) system call.

Comment: `sem_t` is not part of the C standard library

Comment: @qz- yes your right, I just changed it then to POSIX